# AnalysisException: The namespace in session catalog must have exactly one name part: dss.raw.abc;

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am trying to fetch data from snowflake table, using databrick job.
This query:

**select * from from dss.raw.abc**

Here: dss is database, raw is schema and abc is table name.

When I am executing this query its throwing error:
**AnalysisException: The namespace in session catalog must have exactly one name part: dss.raw.abc;**

This is my actual statement.

spark.sql(f"""select * from from dss.raw.abc""").show()

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I fixed it by using a cluster that has permission and access to the database I was trying to access.

Ensure you are using a cluster machine connected to the database and have the right permissions.